# Unable to google login: auth/redirect-cancelled-by-user

Tags: cordova, firebase-authentication

I have followed all the steps listed here:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova, verified all the information but I am still getting the error below.

```
code: "auth/redirect-cancelled-by-user", message: "The redirect operation has been cancelled by the user before finalizing."
```

1. I have the correct config information in my app
2. My firebase config matches my firebase's console's config.
3. I have the correct dynamic link.
4. I have installed all the required plugins
5. SHA certificate fingerprints are added.
6. Project has been given the name under google login settings in Firebase console.

Here is how I'm calling google login:

consturctor has `public afAuth: AngularFireAuth`. And couple relevant imports are:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';

// signInWithGoogle.
  signInWithGoogle(): void {
    this.showLoading();
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      console.log("android");
      this.provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(this.provider)
        .then(function () {
          return firebase.auth().getRedirectResult();
        })
        .then((result: any) => {
          if (result) {
            this.handleUser(result);
          }
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
          this.hideLoading();
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log("android login error: ", error);
        });
    }
    if (this.platform.is('core')) {
      console.log("in core");
      this.provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(this.provider)
        .then((result: any) => {
          if (result) {
            this.handleUser(result);
          }
        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
          this.hideLoading();
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log("error: ", error);
        });
    }
  }
```

Above is my complete method.

Below is a test project so I'll show all the settings:

```
<universal-links>
    <host name="bhb7m.app.goo.gl" scheme="https" />
    <host name="test1-2366d.firebaseapp.com" scheme="https">
        <path url="/__/auth/callback" />
    </host>
</universal-links>
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleTask" />
```

[image: Dynamic Link]
[image: Android Settings]

[image: Webapp config]
[image: Android Menifest]

I guess I must be missing a step because I can't get it to work at all.

Comment: When you finish sign in, does it close the Chrome Custom tab (where you signed in to the OAuth provider) on its own or does it remain open until you manually close it (click the close button)? Also try to check you are detecting the incoming link correctly: `universalLinks.subscribe(null, function (eventData) {console.log(eventData.url);});`  If not there may be an issue with your FDL configuration for some reason.

Comment: bojeil Thank you. It closes the chrome custom tab automatically.

Comment: Could my SHA being used in other projects effect this?

Comment: If it closes automatically, it means FDL is configured correctly. However, there could be an issue with your config.xml or JS code. can you check `universalLinks.subscribe(null, function (eventData) {console.log(eventData.url);});` ? you want to ensure the plugin is detecting the incoming link.

Comment: bojeil, I'm not sure how to call that command in ionic2.

Comment: Add that code in your JS. Include it on `deviceready`.

Comment: Can you give me a working example please? I'm not sure of all the imports and all. And it will go in my login function right?

Comment: It can go anywhere. Check https://github.com/nordnet/cordova-universal-links-plugin You can add it to `onDeviceReady`. It is only for testing that the plugin is detecting the link.

Comment: I have the plugin installed. I removed it and re-added it just to refresh. But I am still not sure how to call that command.

Comment: Can you explain what imports I will need? Did you try to set this up yourself?

Comment: Yes, i have set this up several times in the past. I don't know how much clearer I can get but in order to properly debug the root cause of this, you have to add that code snippet ondeviceready and check if the incoming link is detected by the universallinks plugin.

Comment: I am having the same problem, but using firebaseUI. I DO see the universal link callback, with an object with a `deepLink` property whose value is `"https://nims-blue.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/callback?fdlDomain=wue95.app.goo.gl&platform=android&appIdentifier=in.nemmadi.dsnag&authDomain=nims-blue.firebaseapp.com&link=https://nims-blue.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/callback?state%3D[...long hex stuff..]Hjw5IdXv9OxuIpc5354-M9lcfh1Vrm-9I%26authuser%3D0%26session_state%3D72ba6462ff8764d0bc5f01167ac56ae94e0fb3e2..f5e4%26prompt%3Dnone&appName=dSnag!"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was with dependencies. I updated to Cordova 8.0 and then I started to get build errors.

Comment: You updated to Cordova 8.0 and that did solve your problem? Or it was what caused the problem, and you solved the problem by downgrading again? What was the nature of the problem with dependencies?

Comment: Yeah, updating to Cordova 8.0 was the problem. I didn't put those relevant logs. And yes, downgrading fixed the problem. I think I would get errors when I did cordova prepare -verbose.

Comment: Which version did you downgrade to?

Comment: Downgraded to 7.